# HX711 module and NodeMCU devkit 0.9

Tags: nodemcu

Good morning.

I have a NodeMCU devkit 0.9 and I am trying to interface it with a load cell amplifier (HX711), which I saw has libraries for NodeMCU.

I tried 2 options:

- Custom build from nodemcu-build.com for master and dev branches. After flashing the bin file and opening ESPlorer /dev/ttyUSBx port I tried to upload the basic web server code from [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2015/10/29/getting-started-with-nodemcu-board-powered-by-esp8266-wisoc/). But when I go to the browser and type the IP nothing is displayed.
- Build my own firmware, uncommenting the HX711 module and limiting my flash size to 4M and use esp-open-sdk to have the xtensa-lx106-elf module. After building without errors I flashed the generated bin file and the same thing happened. The web server doesn't seem to be running.
  I am a bit confused because the only bin that is working with my devkit 0.9 board is the last one available in the releases, which is the 0.9.6-dev_20150704, but this one doesn't have the modules I need to proceed with my HX711 project.

When I build using the 1.4/1.5/2.0 NodeMCU firmware I'm not able to get the same things working (at least the web server basic code). I tried several combinations of user configs (baud rate, activating devkit 0.9 define, develop mode, auto flash vs 4M flash).

What procedures should I follow to have the HX711 working with the NodeMCU devkit 0.9?

Best regards.

Comment: Contrary to what the title suggests you don't have any issues with HX711, right? Stick to the binary you get from the cloud builder for now to rule out a whole heap of pitfalls. In general I advice you start small by e.g. first working with the example in the documentation e.g. https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netsocketsend